# Generating chained dynamic drop downs using ajax and java script

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to do the cascading drop down in country,state and city .

In this my problem is,country drop down shows the thous values, but country related states are not showing in the state drop down and as well city also.

I am trying in the spring tool suits.

my problem is that country drop down shows the thous values, but country related states are not showing in the state drop down and as well city also.

```
    index.jsp
    
    <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Dynamic Dependent Select Box Using jQuery, Ajax & JSP with MySql</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function country_change()
    {
         var x = document.getElementById("country").selectedIndex;
          alert(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value);
          
          debugger;
        var country = $(".country").val();
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "state.jsp",
            data: "country_id="+country,
            
            cache: false,
            success: function(response)
            
            {
    
                $(".state").html(response);
            }
        });
    }
    function state_change()
    {
        var state = $(".state").val();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "city.jsp",
            data: "state_id="+state,
            
            cache: false,
            success: function(response)
            {
                $(".city").html(response);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    
    <style>
    label
    {
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px;
    }
    div
    {
        margin-top:100px;
    }
    select
    {
        width:200px;
        height:35px;
    }
    </style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <center>
        <div>
    
        <label>Country :</label> 
        <select id="country" onclick="country_change()">
        <option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
        
        <%
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //load driver
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dynamic_db","root","root"); //create connection
                    
            PreparedStatement pstmt=null ; //create statement
                    
            pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select country_id,country_name from country"); //sql select query
           
            ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery(); //execute query and set in resultset object rs.
                    
            while(rs.next())
            {
            %>
                <option value="<%=rs.getInt("country_id")%>">
                     
                    <%=rs.getString("country_name")%>
                </option>
               
            <%
            
         
            }
               
            con.close(); //close connection
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e);
        }
        %>
        </select>
    
        <label>State :</label> 
        <select class="state" onchange="state_change()">
        <option selected="selected">--Select State--</option>
        </select>
    
        <label>City :</label> 
        <select class="city">
        <option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
        </select>
    
        </div>
        <br />
            
        </center>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    
    
    
    state.jsp
    
    <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
    
    <%
    if(request.getParameter("country_id")!=null) 
    {
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("country_id")); //get country_id from index.jsp page with function country_change() through ajax and store in id variable
            System.out.println(id+"country");
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //load driver
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dynamic_db","root","root"); //create connection
                
            PreparedStatement pstmt=null ; //create statement
                    
            pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select state_id,state_name,country_id from state where country_id=?"); //sql select query
            pstmt.setInt(1,id);
            ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery(); //execute query and set in resultset object rs.
            %>        
                <option selected="selected">--Select State--</option>
            <%    
            while(rs.next())
            {
            %>        
                <option value="<%=rs.getInt("state_id")%>">
                    <%=rs.getString("state_name")%>
                </option>
            <%
        
            }
            
            con.close(); //close connection
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e);
        }
    }
    %>

city.jsp

<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
if(request.getParameter("state_id")!=null) 
{
    int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("state_id")); //get state_id from index.jsp page with function state_change() through ajax and store in id variable.
        
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //load driver
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dynamic_db","root","root"); //create connection
            
        PreparedStatement pstmt=null ; //create statement
                
        pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from city where state_id=? "); //sql select query
        pstmt.setInt(1,id);
        ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery(); //execute query and set in resultset object rs.
        %>        
            <option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
        <%    
        while(rs.next())
        {
        %> 
            <option value="<%=rs.getInt("city_id")%>">
                <%=rs.getString("city_name")%>
            </option>
        <%
        }
        
        con.close(); //close connection 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e);
    }
}
%>
```

I expects the output in when ever select country in country drop down automatically shows the selected country related states and state related city's in  drop down.

But the actual output show the only country in country's drop down, whenever the select the country in country's drop down , the country related state are not displayed in the state drop down.

the database  table's details are:  country,state and city.

#### country table:

```
 1.country_id(pk)
 2.Country_name.
```

#### state table:

```
1.state_id (pk).
2.state_name.
3.country_id (fk).
```

#### city table:

```
1.city_id (pk).
2.city_name.
3.state_id (fk).
```

thous are the database table fields.

I am also try the normally cascading drop down its work, but i am trying to fetch the values from database, it's not working .

It's showing the only the country's values ,the country related states and state related city's not fetching .

In database three tables are the relationship using the primary key and foreign key.
But shows the only country's values  in the country drop down.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here so can you help me?

I want to create a cascading drop-down menu and I can't see what I am doing wrong. I've tried everything. I am just out of ideas.

please provide the  solution.

Thank you